# Chamada a evento jQuery não funcionando

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tenho um botão no qual adiciona alguns componentes na tela (input, drop down etc...), via manipulação jQuery. Dentre esses componentes dois botoes, respectivamente um de "Salvar" e outro de "Cancelar".

```
$('#show-destination').click(function () {

       $('.ms-selection ul.ms-list li').each(function() {
            if ($(this).hasClass('ms-selected')) {              
                $('#negotiation-status').prepend('<h5 id="destination-title"> <b>Destino: </b>' + $(this).text()+'</h5>');

                $('#destination-title').after('<div id="div-departure" class="box01"></div>');
                $('#div-departure').append('<div id="div-input-departure" class="input-group "></div');
                $('#div-input-departure').append('<span id="span-departure" class="input-group-addon btn-success"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>');
                $('#span-departure').after('<input id="input-departure" type="text" name="customerService.destinationRequested.departureDate" class="form-control" placeholder="Data de Ida"/>');

                $('#div-departure').after('<div id="div-arrive" class="box02"></div>');
                $('#div-arrive').append('<div id="div-input-arrive" class="input-group "></div');
                $('#div-input-arrive').append('<span id="span-arrive" class="input-group-addon btn-success"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>');
                $('#span-arrive').after('<input id="input-arrive" type="text" name="customerService.destinationRequested.arriveDate" class="form-control" placeholder="Data de Volta"/>');

                //Valor e Tipo
                $('#div-arrive').after('<div id="div-sale-type" class="box01"></div>');
                $('#div-sale-type').append('<select id="combo-saleType" name="" class="form-control"></select>');


                $('#div-sale-type').after('<div id="input-div" class="box02"></div>');
                $('#input-div').append('<div id="acme" class="input-group "></div>');
                $('#acme').append('<span id="span-batatinhya" class="input-group-addon btn-success"><i class="fa fa-money"></i></span>');
                $('#span-batatinhya').after('<input id="input-price" type="text" name="customerService.destinationRequested.price" class="form-control"/>');


                //Botoes que são adicionados
                $('#input-div').after('<div id="div-button" class="box03"></div>');
                $('#div-button').append('<button id="button-add-destination" type="button" class="btn btn-info pull-right"><span class="entypo-plus-squared"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Adicionar</button>');
                $('#button-add-destination').before('<button id="button-cancel-destination" type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-right"><span class="entypo-cancel-squared"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Cancelar</button>');

            }
          });      
   });
```

Bem, o problema é que esses botões disparam um requisição AJAX que no caso não funciona. Ou seja, meu botão `#button-add-destinatio` chama a função:

```
   $('#button-add-destination').click(function (){
       var departure =  $('#input-departure').val();
       var arrive = $('#input-arrive').val();
       var ckb = $('#ckb-label').val();
       var price = $('#input-price').val();
       var saleType = $('#ckb-saleType').val();

       $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: "departure="+departure+"&"+"arrive="+arrive+"price"+price+"saleType"+saleType+"ckb"+ckb,
        url:'/viatge/auth/addSelectedDestination?${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}',
        sucess: function(result){
            alert("Destino adcionado com sucesso!");
        },
        error: function(error){
            alert(error);
        }
       })
   });
```

Mas a chamada não ocorre! O que ocorre?

Comment: Como sabe que a chamada não ocorre? O `$('#button-add-destination').click(function (){` é corrido? Esse data devia ser um objeto...

Comment: já olhou no seu console? lança alguma exceção?

Comment: Simplesmente pelo fato que quando estou debungando o mesmo não entra no metodo. O data ele pega diretamente no componente. Não lança exceção!

Comment: Uma coisa estranha é que se eu deixo o botão fixo na minha arvore DOM ai a função e disparada. Só não funciona quando o jQuery monta a estrutura.

Comment: O que quer dizer com "deixo o botão fixo"? Ele é retirado e colocado novamente no DOM?

Comment: @Sergio, se eu coloco ele "na mão" na tela ele chama o  função de click, mas se eu deixo da forma que coloquei acima (o jQuery renderizando dinamicamente) não funciona.

Comment: @Sergio, infelizmente não funcionou também.

Comment: @JoãoManolo pode criar um exemplo no jsFiddle que reproduza o problema? Sem isso não dá para testar.

Comment: E veja na página se o URL está correto aqui: `'/viatge/auth/addSelectedDestination?${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}',` quando chega ao lado do cliente

Comment: Sim @Sergio. Acho que fica mais claro para visualizar. Já posto o link. Com relação a chamada AJAX está tudo ok. O problema e disparar o evento, coisa que não acontece nem com reza...

Comment: Aqui está ele: http://jsfiddle.net/joaoManolo/6fLj3cdg/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

João, o botão que tu tem o listner também é inserido em tempo de execução, portando quando tu ele entra no DOM, já foi executado o comando Jquery de .click, que não o encontra, e portanto, não faz nada.

O que tu deve fazer é pegar algum elemento que já está no DOM, que não seja inserido por ajax, como o HTML, por exemplo, mas é melhor por algum mais especifico que seja pai mais próximo, e colocar o listner 'on', exemplo:

```
 $('html').on('click', '#button-add-destination', function (){
alert('hello!');
})
```

Pode ser que o erro seja outro, mas me parece que isso pode funcionar.

Comment: Funcionou sim @Luiz Rossi, agora tudo ficou mais claro. Vai me ajudar muito, pois tenho bastante manipulação do DOM para fazer. Obrigado pela força